# db-mysql installation error using npm

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install db-mysql module for node.js using

**sudo npm install db-mysql**

but I am getting the following error:

```
npm WARN package.json hbase@0.0.5 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json log4js@0.2.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json mime@1.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json restler@2.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json db-mysql@0.7.6 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/db-mysql

> db-mysql@0.7.6 install /home/lifemap/lifemap-upload-master/node_modules/db-mysql
> node-waf configure build

sh: 1: node-waf: not found

> db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall /home/lifemap/lifemap-upload-master/node_modules/db-mysql
> rm -rf build/*

npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 127
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls db-mysql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-54-virtual
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "db-mysql"
npm ERR! cwd /home/lifemap/lifemap-upload-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lifemap/lifemap-upload-master/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0`
```

Is there any other command or version I need to use or install for db-mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the root cause of the problem

> sh: 1: node-waf: not found

**node-waf** has been replaced by **node-gyp** in Node 0.8, so you won't be able to build this module, unless you will fork the module and will change it to use node-gyp. Basically, seems that db-mysql is not actively supported anymore.

As a replacement, you could use [mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) module, which is actively supported.

Answer (score -1):

You can try one of [this](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) method without having to `sudo`. Hope it'll work!